# Class constructor overloading in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, constructor, constructor-overloading

I am working on a class `PlaybackControl`, I use it to create two HTMLElements:

1. `PlaybackControlButton: HTMLButtonElement`
2. `PlaybackControlMenu: HTMLDivElement`

Now, to initialise the class object, I need three arguments:

1. `videoPlayer: HTMLVideoElement`
2. `playbackRates: PlaybackRates`
3. `options: PlaybackControlOptions`

where:

```js
type Shortcuts = Record<string, { key: string, value: string }>
type PlaybackRates = string[]

interface ShortcutsEnabled {
  enableShortcuts: true
  shortcuts: Shortcuts
}

interface ShortcutsDisabled {
  enableShortcuts: false
}

interface DefaultOptions extends ShortcutsEnabled {}

type PlaybackControlOptions = DefaultOptions | ShortcutsDisabled
```

Also, I have default values for all of them,

1. `videoPlayer` default to `document.querySelector('video') as HTMLVideoElement`
2. `playbackRates` defaults to a static attribute `PlaybackControl.DEFAULT_PLAYBACK_RATES`
3. `options` defaults to `{ enableShortcuts: true, shortcuts: PlaybackControl.DEFAULT_SHORTCUTS }`

Now, I want to create an overloaded constructor which should work in all cases:

1. No arguments passed
2. Any combination of arguments passed
   Any value not given should fallback to its default,

Lastly, `videoPlayer: HTMLVideoElement` is the only argument which I want to store as a class attribute, rest two are just arguments which I just want to some function calls in the constructor (because I have no later use for them).

Currently, the constructor that I wrote is:

```js
constructor (videoPlayer?: HTMLVideoElement, playbackRates: PlaybackRates = PlaybackControl.DEFAULT_PLAYBACK_RATES, options: PlaybackControlOptions = { enableShortcuts: true, shortcuts: PlaybackControl.DEFAULT_SHORTCUTS })
```

while this does allow me to initialise without any argument but this fails when I try to:

`new PlaybackControl({ enableShortcuts: false })`

and VSCode shows error that:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'enableShortcuts' does not exist in type 'HTMLVideoElement'.
```

while I do understand the underlying problem (I guess), I am unable to resolve this.
Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

1. Since, verbal descriptions might be hard to dive in, [here](https://github.com/DarhkVoyd/toppings/blob/3db3031f5a982e4daf64b9198524c5c0a35bebd6/src/content_scripts/components/PlaybackControl/index.ts#L61) you can find the entire code to run.
2. By `any combination of arguments` clarification:
   I should be able to give whatever argument I want to set manually (in order with some missing) and the rest fallback to default

Comment: ① Could you please provide a [mre] that we can just copy and paste into our own IDEs to get started on this?  Right now we have to revere-engineer code from verbal descriptions (e.g., "I have a class named" "it has static attributes") and it makes it harder to jump in.  Make it easier for us and you'll have a higher chance of getting an answer that helps.  ② What does "any combination of arguments" mean?  Any order at all?  Same order with some missing?

Comment: Assuming so, you could try [this](//tsplay.dev/mZy7aN), but it's fragile and complicated. And it becomes impossible for multiple params of the same type.  Why not just have a single constructor arg object, like `arg: {videoPlayer?: HTMLVideoElement, playbackRates?: PlaybackRates, options?: PlaybackControlOptions}` and then you don't have to worry about supporting the "tossing everything into an unlabeled bag and then trying to fish the appropriate things out of the bag". Anyway does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I have added the link to the code which you can run. I initially planned to use a single constructor arg object, but since I am currently learning Typescript, I figured using this approach I will learn with practice about constructor overloading and function signatures. If this won't work I will use the object approach.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you so much for your answer, it really helped me and your implementation of `AnySubset` is impressive. I am going with both of your's suggestion to avoid the trouble and just use an object instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that your *implementation* of the constructor will be crazy, as it searches through the inputs for the properties of the right types.  It essentially requires that no two parameters are of the same type, since otherwise there's an ambiguity... what if you had `a: string, b: string`?  And the caller writes `new X("c")`?  Which argument should be set to `"c"`?  For your code as written the implementation might be something like

```
class PlaybackControl {
  static DEFAULT_PLAYBACK_RATES = [];
  static DEFAULT_SHORTCUTS = {};
  constructor(
    ...args: ???) {
    const a: (HTMLVideoElement | PlaybackRates | PlaybackControlOptions)[] = args;
    const videoPlayer = a.find((x): x is HTMLVideoElement =>
      x instanceof HTMLVideoElement);
    const playbrackRates = a.find((x): x is PlaybackRates =>
      Array.isArray(x) && x.every(e => typeof e === "string")
    ) ?? PlaybackControl.DEFAULT_PLAYBACK_RATES;
    const options: PlaybackControlOptions = a.find((x): x is PlaybackControlOptions =>
      x && typeof x === "object" && "enableShortcuts" in x
    ) ?? { enableShortcuts: true, shortcuts: PlaybackControl.DEFAULT_SHORTCUTS };
  }
}
```

That should work and behave how you like, but it's so fragile.

---

Anyway, assuming you do want such an implementation, there remains the question of how to *type* it.  You say the input must be  `videoPlayer: HTMLVideoElement, playbackRates: PlaybackRates, options: PlaybackControlOptions` in order with some possibly missing, so, for example, you're not going to pass in `options` before `videoPlayer` if they both exist.

You could just manually [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) the constructor to accept every possible input combination.  But I like playing with types, so let's write a `Subsequence<T>` utility type that takes an input [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `T` and produces a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of every possible [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of `T`.

Then the constructor input could be:

```
type Subsequence<T extends any[]> =
  T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? [F, ...Subsequence<R>] | Subsequence<R> : []
```

That gives

```
type X = Subsequence<[videoPlayer: HTMLVideoElement, playbackRates: PlaybackRates, options: PlaybackControlOptions]>;
/* type X = [] | [PlaybackControlOptions] | [PlaybackRates] | [PlaybackRates, PlaybackControlOptions] | 
  [HTMLVideoElement] | [HTMLVideoElement, PlaybackControlOptions] | [HTMLVideoElement, PlaybackRates] | 
  [HTMLVideoElement, PlaybackRates, PlaybackControlOptions] */
```

And thus the full constructor looks like

```
class PlaybackControl {
  static DEFAULT_PLAYBACK_RATES = [];
  static DEFAULT_SHORTCUTS = {};
  constructor(
    ...args: Subsequence<[videoPlayer: HTMLVideoElement, playbackRates: PlaybackRates, options: PlaybackControlOptions]>
  ) {
    const a: (HTMLVideoElement | PlaybackRates | PlaybackControlOptions)[] = args;
    const videoPlayer = a.find((x): x is HTMLVideoElement =>
      x instanceof HTMLVideoElement);
    const playbrackRates = a.find((x): x is PlaybackRates =>
      Array.isArray(x) && x.every(e => typeof e === "string")
    ) ?? PlaybackControl.DEFAULT_PLAYBACK_RATES;
    const options: PlaybackControlOptions = a.find((x): x is PlaybackControlOptions =>
      x && typeof x === "object" && "enableShortcuts" in x
    ) ?? { enableShortcuts: true, shortcuts: PlaybackControl.DEFAULT_SHORTCUTS };
  }
}
```

And it behaves as desired.

```
new PlaybackControl({ enableShortcuts: false })
```

---

But, is it worth it? Almost certainly not.  Crazy implementation plus crazy typings equals too much crazy.  The conventional way to do something like this is to take a single object input of type `{videoPlayer?: HTMLVideoElement, playbackRates?: PlaybackRates, options?: PlaybackControlOptions}` to take advantage of the natural indifference to property order that objects in JavaScript give you.  The ambiguity goes away (e.g., `{a?: string, b?: string}` would require either `{a: "c"}` or `{b: "c"}`, and the typing is very straightforward.  So you should do that instead.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#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-SQVxed1sSgA3CoAPQAKigBygMvwdg+jI9ztDl2u-qjWesOaMJm9fOzwed5fMLFLHDz4YLtwWldS1n1xrN6oQlogNv6lc7htN5r71tt9erZwuzcjbeLXbHvf7g7tQeONddWHbERH3fHa6nm6dZZ3063s7DEcLi8T8YcqB0WBwDabVzCESophoqAevjEgAggAqkaMIAPqaEaQEAJoAEJAacADSEEEEBMK+DAsp2HG37AL+-4VIBoHgRBMC6pMBAwqcIEwth+CsAoeFQCQCzJKgwDIAAFKkESsqISAMIGAqciKSoquOWo6lAy49hak79PaM5em6p6erWPpQH6raBu+c63rp0apAAlF+ESsXcwDInw3FyUeinWZ8DaaVm+k3i2AYmZm+CCcJLERGxVBQKqvbSUgsqiGSLj0KQ3HcUsJl8EsUDVLJo7yROA62ngqgWRZKX0D+UIai46WHqujkmQFlnsVADrHEg27epF0WxfFiXJalb4qa5uB5flUBAUgTUgGS1TDaNCVmQAZDNUBLGSEDCEUIDcdA-UpkCCBlRtuD4AARFYDAHSZfFQGZdIMu5+ZksRwFgZB0FwYhKFoRhWE1UF1k6QG7oqR+nl3K1MVrB1SULd16m5gZQNvP150RClc1bZAO2Q-th0IHoABWxDAAdUAowdTQxJsPiE-QC3nZdDLsKTwTk4kKZIFILBYK0mTQ9et33aRkEUVRNF0dhzGpPk+QqHQEAAO7c42sPcfT0SM5zzOdN0igmUAA)

Answer (score 1):

> it this fails when I try to:
>
> ```
> new PlaybackControl({ enableShortcuts: false })
> ```

I would not attempt to overload the constructor to accept this. It would need to check whether the first argument is a dom element or an options object, and then shuffle the arguments into the respective variables. This leads to rather ugly code and complicated type signatures.

Rather, to skip passing the first two arguments, pass `undefined` for them, then pass your options object as the third argument:

```
new PlaybackControl(undefined, undefined, { enableShortcuts: false })
```

If this is a common usage, consider changing your constructor to only accept one single object parameter, so that you'd call

```
new PlaybackControl({ options: { enableShortcuts: false } })
```

Comment: Would it still be a problem, if the arguments are always in the same order with some just missing so you don't have to shuffle them. 

I understand that just passing `undefined` would solve the problem, but I don't feel manually passing `undefined` makes sense. I prefer the argument object approach better than this.

I plan to use the object approach if this doesn't work, but since I am currently learning Typescript, I figured using this approach I will learn with practice about constructor overloading and function signatures.

Comment: Yes, I had assumed fixed order, no shuffling. It's still ugly and complicated, 3 optional parameters already makes 8 different signatures. And distinguishing which value was passed where (i.e. whether and how many were skipped) is not trivial, and depends on the parameters having different types, which is why this approach has generally fallen out of favour. See the playground code linked by @jcalz in his comment though (which doesn't even spell out the overloading, it goes full into generics right away).

Comment: I do get your point but could you please tell me why wouldn't something like this work??

`constructor ()`
`constructor (videoPlayer: HTMLVideoElement)`
`constructor (playbackRates: PlaybackRates)`
`constructor (options: PlaybackControlOptions)`
... and so on until
`constructor (videoPlayer: HTMLVideoElement, playbackRates: PlaybackRates options: PlaybackControlOptions) {}`

Comment: It *would* work, it's just a lot "and so on" :P

Comment: I tried it but I get error: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.
So, could you please help me to make just these three cases work:
1. No argument
2. All Argument
3. Just the options argument. 

You could find the my current implementation [here](https://github.com/DarhkVoyd/toppings/blob/3db3031f5a982e4daf64b9198524c5c0a35bebd6/src/content_scripts/components/PlaybackControl/index.ts#L61)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it really helped with my problem.  I am going with both of your's suggestion to avoid the trouble and just use an object instead.

Comment: The implementation signature would basically need to be `constructor (first?: HTMLVideoElement | PlaybackRates | PlaybackControlOptions, second?: PlaybackRates | PlaybackControlOptions, third?: PlaybackControlOptions) {}` or the think that jcalz cooked up

Comment: If this answer has helped you and solved your problem, please consider [upvoting and/or accepting it](/help/someone-answers)